# How can I get result out of this arrangement of processes and threads?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following arrangement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import time
import re
import os
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

from sphinx_intl import catalog as c
from translation_finder import TranslationFinder
from definition import Definitions as df
from testFindResult import makeBatches, PatternFoundResult, FormatUpperCase, findEachMessage, FormatBase

class FindPatternProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self,
                 start_time,
                 tf: TranslationFinder,
                 pat: re.Pattern,
                 batch,
                 exit_cond,
                 queue,
                 ): ### new code
        super(FindPatternProcess, self).__init__()
        self.batch = batch
        self.tf: TranslationFinder = tf
        self.exit_cond = exit_cond ### new code
        self.result_queue = queue
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.pat = pat
        self.tf: TranslationFinder

    def updateResult(self, result):
        (execution_time, line_number, proc_name, return_values) = result
        # self.result_queue.put(return_values)
        print(return_values)

    def run(self):
        start_time = self.start_time
        formatter = FormatUpperCase()
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            thread_list = [
                executor.submit(findEachMessage, start_time, m, self.tf, formatter, self.pat)
                for m in self.batch]

            # done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait(thread_list, return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
            for th in concurrent.futures.as_completed(thread_list):
                try:
                    result = th.result(timeout=5)
                    list(filter(self.updateResult, result))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e, th)
                    raise e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    home_dev = os.environ['DEV']
    input_path = os.path.join(home_dev, "current_blender_manual_merge_flat_0001.po")
    input_cat = c.load_po(input_path)

    BaseManager.register('PatternFoundResult', PatternFoundResult)
    BaseManager.register('TranslationFinder', TranslationFinder)
    manager = BaseManager()
    manager.start()

    tf = manager.TranslationFinder()
    pat = df.UPPERCASE_UNTRANSLATED_PATTERN

    batch_list = makeBatches(input_cat)
    exit_cond = multiprocessing.Event()
    batch_len = len(batch_list)
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    result = PatternFoundResult('df.UPPERCASE_UNTRANSLATED_PATTERN')
    result.output_file = 'findNonMulti.po'
    result.output_text_file = 'findNonMulti.txt'

    procs = {}
    exit_cond = multiprocessing.Event() ### new code

    for (index, batch) in enumerate(batch_list):
        p = FindPatternProcess(start_time, tf, pat, batch, exit_cond, queue)
        procs[index] = p

    for (index, p) in procs.items():
        p.start()

    time.sleep(1)

    exit_cond.set() ### new code
    for (index, p) in procs.items():
        print('JOIN process:', p)
        p.join()

    print(f'Execution took {time.perf_counter() - start_time} seconds')
```

And I don't know who to get results out of thread and then collecting it at the end. Using the multiprocessing Queue make the code pausing at the end. I don't know why. Could you please explain what I am doing wrong? I have to temporarily just printout the return values and the code works, running at:

Execution took 20.5175720369989 seconds

and all processes are JOINED, for instance:

JOIN process:

Thank you.

Comment: Here you can download the zip file I am using, all the codes (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eKSrZTuKKtDauX33DEBBuZw-lQc9A7YP/view?usp=sharing) and data, You will need to run ```python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt``` attached to install sphinx stuff.

Comment: Don't worry I have solved it, just using manager to create an instance of PatternFoundResult and pass it in the place of multiprocessing Queue and wait to get the result at the end.